# Стерео в моно в реальном времени

Tags: windows, аудио, windows-10

У меня есть возможность вывести только правый канал. Есть ли какой-то способ программно сделать [stereo ---> Mono] или [R-L ---> RL] сразу для всех приложений?

Answer (score -1):

Идёте в `Панель управления/Специальные возможности/Звук`, нажимаете "Включить монозвук". Примерно как на скриншоте ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]